# I'm new to MVC and C# and am getting this error The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ienumerable, enumerable

I'm getting the following error and am not sure how to fix it.I'm trying to display a list from a SQL table. I used a scaffolding to generate the index.cshtml

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[NutritionZone.Web.Models.Entities.NzSite,NutritionZone.Shared.DTOs.SiteDto]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[NutritionZone.Web.ViewModels.SiteViewModel]'.

```
Controller:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using NutritionZone.Web.Models;


namespace NutritionZone.Web.Controllers
{
    public class SiteController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Site
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            using (SiteModel DBSite = new SiteModel())
            {
                return View(DBSite.Sites.ToList());

            }
               
        }

        // GET: Site/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // GET: Site/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Site/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: Site/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Site/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add update logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: Site/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Site/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add delete logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<NutritionZone.Web.Models.Site>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClaimSiteId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Zip)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ContactPerson)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClaimSiteId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Zip)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContactPerson)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhoneNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```